# Logical drives of current user

Tags: drive

I get only the logical drives for computer with

```
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_MappedLogicalDisk");
```

But I need all logical drives including user mapped logical drives.

Thanks

Urs

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I was running the programm in visual studio with admin rights. I this case the user mapped drives are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

It works for admin also with

```
        var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

when the registry entry

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

EnableLinkedConnections

is set to DWORD (32 Bit) with value 1.